# CSS Selector: Don't show empty DIV with no background image?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have an element like this:

```
<div id="banner" style="background-image: url('')"></div>
```

I see that I can hide the empty div using this CSS:

```
div:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

But what I want to do is only hide the div when the background image url is empty (as above). Can that be done in CSS?

Comment: Be careful with empty urls as they will do a server request!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `css`. Add these lines

```
div[style="background-image: url('')"] {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try it:

```
div[style*="url('')"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Genius! Thank -you!